# short / clear word for constituent?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I'm a programmer looking to name a variable, so extra points for brevity (characters in word) and clarity.

I have many objects which can be aggregated such that one of them acts as a stand in and participates in some process the others do not.  What word can I use to describe a member of the set of objects represented by another object?

"constituent" jumped out right away, but its 11 characters and potentially confusing to non-native speakers who read my code.  is there a shorter / simpler word which is as specific?

Comment: Hello, eretmochelys. Coining of terms for use in computing is expressly off-topic on ELU. Perhaps you'd like to try over on Computer Science SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for a new computerese term.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, sorry I didn't know this was off topic in ELU.  if its significant, know that this term is specific to my program here (not a generic comp sci term), though I respect your decision.  thanks for the prompt reply :)

Comment: That's the reason _why_ such questions are off-topic here. ELU is aimed at trying to establish _what is_ normal usage, and analysing it.

Comment: does 'donkey' fit?

Comment: @eretmochelys Did you look in a thesaurus for synonyms? That should be your first stop.

Comment: sorry, this is definitely off topic per [rules](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), there's quite a bit on meta about why this ought to be the case.  I'll be sure to do some more reading before my next post.  Thanks for your help, sorry to have taken up some editing time.

Answer (score 0):

How about *representative* or *representative element*? Mathematics uses similar terms for quotient constructions in algebra and topology, in which a set is partitioned into classes, and the relationships between classes are defined by analogous relationships between arbitrarily selected elements of each class.